# How to bind and change pages in a tab control with a viewmodel?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, tabcontrol

I have three xaml pages and related ViewModels: main.xaml, MainViewModel.cs; page1.xaml, Page1ViewModel.cs; page2.xaml, page2ViewModel.cs. There is a TabControl in main.xaml.
I want to load and show the page1.xaml in TabItem when the application initializing, and page1.xaml will be changed to page2.xaml when clicking the button included in page1.xaml; page2.xaml will be changed to page1.xaml when clicking the button included in page2.xaml.

All the events or commands need to be implemented in ViewModels. My Questions:

1. How to load the pages to the TabItem?
2. How to change the page in the TabItem?

Above questions have been solved by Rachel, Thanks.

1. I want show page1 and page2 in TabItem1, page1 will disappear and page2 will show when clicking the button which included in page1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainPageViewModel` should hold a collection of what pages are in the TabControl, and the SelectedPage. It should also contain an `ICommand` which will change the current page.

For example,

```
// These should be full properties that raise PropertyChange notifications
public ObservableCollection<IPageViewModel> Tabs { get; set; }
public int SelectedTabIndex { get; set; }
private ICommand ChangeTabIndexCommand { get; set; }

MainPageViewModel()
{
    Tabs = new ObservableCollection<IPageViewModel>();

    Tabs.Add(new Page1ViewModel());
    Tabs.Add(new Page2VieWModel());

    SelectedTab = 0;

    ChangeTabIndexCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(ChangeTab);
}

void ChangeTab(int newIndex)
{
    if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < Tabs.Count())
        SelectedTab = newIndex;
}
```

Your MainView would look like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" />
```

If you are using Silverlight 5, I believe you can use implicit `DataTemplates`, however if not you'll have to use something like a `DataTemplateSelector` or a `Converter` to tell Silverlight how to draw each ViewModel. I usually use [Microsoft PRISM's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) `DataTemplateSelector`

There are a number of ways to hook up the `ChangeTabIndexCommand`. My preference is to use some kind of [Messaging System](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/), however you could also hook up the event in the Constructor of the MainViewModel.

Comment: Rachel, Thanks for your answer, its userful for me. And there are some others questions: How to show different page in a TabItem, and how to public the event incude in the page(not the main page) to load the other page in the same TabItem. Thanks.